# How to extract sender name from emails containing multiple human names?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

Suppose I have a set of emails which contains human names. I managed to extract named entity using natural language processing. But I want to specifically extract sender name alone from this set of name. What is the standard method for doing this?

Comment: I would suppose that the sender name can be found in some special formula at the end of the mail, so just apply NER to the email ending or to the header. If there is none, try to parse the sender's email adress. If that's not possible, I do not even knnow how a human is able to identify the sender, unless the sender talks of himself in third person :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? Or a synthetic version if there is sensitive information? It is hard to provide help without more details about your problem.